# File extension for text JXA scripts

Tags: music.app, javascript-automation

To get AppleScript scripts to be in the menu of Music.app I can add them as text to `~/Library/Music/Scripts` directory with `.applescript` extension. But what should it be for JavaScript files? At least `.js`, `.javascript`, `.jxa` doesn't create a menu entry.